# Open set containing cantor set

Tags: measure-theory, cantor-set

Is it possible to construct an open set of measure less than a given positive real and containing cantor set?

Comment: I'm curious what motivated the question?  Is this a problem from your text, or a lecture? It just helps us to help you when we know the context in which the question arises.

Comment: Actually i want to know that if a set has finite measure then can we find open set of finite measure containing that set ( every thing in R with Lebesgue measure)

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong. But I guess you can. Just cover the part you want with open interval and take the reamining points. You can see, it is open(in meaning of for example metric spaces.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. The middle-thirds cantor set is constructed as the intersection of nested closed sets $J_n $ of decreasing measure. Each of these closed sets is the union of finitely many closed intervals $I_{n_1},...,I_{n_m}$. Given $\epsilon>0$, find $n $ sufficiently large that the measure of $J_n $ is less than $\epsilon/2$. Let $U_i$ be an open interval of length less than $\epsilon/4n_m$ containing the left endpoint of $I_{n_i}$, and let $V_i$ be an open interval of length less than $\epsilon/4n_m$ containing the right endpoint of $I_{n_i}$. Let $$U_n=\bigcup_{i=1}^{n_m} U_i\cup V_i.$$ Then $U_n$ in an open set of measure less than $\epsilon/2$ which contains all of the endpoints of the intervals $I_{n_i}$. Finally, $A=(\text{int } J_n)\cup U_n$ is an open set containing the cantor set which has measure less than $\epsilon.$